# Chrome.notifications.create does not work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm creating a Chrome extension for the first time.

I've used `chrome.notifications.create` in it, but it does not work! This is my code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('refresh_time',function(items){
    status = $('td.c').next().html();
    if (status.trim() == 'SomeText') {
        alert('Works');
        var opt = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "Project1",
            message: "This is my first extension.",
            iconUrl: "icons/icon-128.png"
        };
        chrome.notifications.create('statusChanged', opt, function(){});
    }
})
```

I get the alarm after execution, but chrome notification does not work! May you tell me what is wrong in my code?

By the way, I used the code below in my **manifest** file.

```
"permissions" : [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "tabs"
]
```

Comment: If some error occurred, you should be able to find the error message on the console tab of the DevTools. Could you confirm it?

Comment: @YoichiroTanaka, nothing ...

Comment: Maybe the notifications are created, but suppressed by OS. Check your tray.

Comment: Make sure you're looking in the right console.

Comment: I think this is a bug as explained here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001031/chrome-web-extension-not-showing-notification-even-though-it-is-working-fine-in?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to make iconUrl a chrome extension path, something like this:

```
iconURL: chrome.runtime.getURL("icons/icon-128.png")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the code is good. However, I guess that you need to confirm the iconUrl path. If the file specified by the path does not exist, the notification will not be displayed. At the time, you may see the following error message on the console tab of the DevTools:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: Unable to download all specified images.
```

You need to specify the valid path for the iconUrl value.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

For me, the notifications were disabled on windows. Make sure that "Get notifications from apps and other senders" is enabled.

Comment: I'd somehow turned off specifically notifications from Chrome and nothing else, go figure.  Thanks for saving me even more time scratching my head over code that was actually working as intended

Answer (score 0):

> Probably, you need to modify the image path as:

```
iconUrl: "../icons/icon-128.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. `iconUrl` path

Your `iconUrl` **SHOULD BE RELATIVE** to your `manifest.json` file.

### 2. Unique notification ID

Chrome notification should have unique ID. I'd suggest you to use like below

```js
/* Set unique ID for each notification */
chrome.notifications.create(`notification-${Date.now()}`, {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: './logo.png', // <------ this should be relative to your manifest.json file.
    title: 'This is a notification title',
    message: 'This is a notification message',
})
```